# Certificate is can not be located in docker container in asp.net core application

Tags: asp.net, docker, .net-core

I am trying to run an identity server application inside a docker container, the Dockerfile build the application but when I run the container, it fails and complains about the not found certificated included in the configuration of the identity server. here is the code

```
var assembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;var 
var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityServerDb");

string cert = environment.ContentRootPath + "/khotabaa.pfx";
Console.WriteLine(cert);
services.AddIdentityServer(options => { options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true; })
//.AddSigningCredential("CN=khotabaa")
.AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(cert, "password"))
```

and the thrown error is:

```
/app/khotabaa.pfx
[20:58:30 Fatal] 
Host terminated unexpectedly.
Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
   at Interop.Crypto.CheckValidOpenSslHandle(SafeHandle handle)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslX509CertificateReader.FromFile(String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password)
   at Service.Khotabaa.Identity.Configuration.IdentityServerConfiguration.AddIdentityServerConfiguration(IServiceCollection services, IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfigurationRoot configuration)
```

Simply its complaning about that the certificate with pfx prefix is not found, while if you look at the WriteLine i added to see if the cert is found, you can see that the .pfx file exist at /app/khotabaa.pfx.

I am really stuck and dont know how to solve this :(

Thats how my Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 5001
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5001

# Prefiltering stage using find -exec and cp --parents to copy out
# the project files in their proper directory structure.
COPY . ./src/
RUN mkdir ./proj && cd ./src && \
    find . -type f -a \( -iname "*.sln" -o -iname "*.csproj" \) \
    -exec cp --parents "{}" ../proj/ \;

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/IdentityApi"
RUN apt-get -y install openssl
RUN pwd
RUN openssl pkcs12 -export -in khotabaa.cer -inkey khotabaa.key -out khotabaa.pfx -passout pass:yb10dj1v

RUN dotnet build "IdentityApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest AS ef-db
RUN pwd
FROM build AS tool
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.dotnet/tools"
RUN pwd
FROM build AS ef
RUN dotnet ef database update -c PersistedGrantDbContext
RUN dotnet ef database update -c ConfigurationDbContext

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "IdentityApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .


ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Service.Khotabaa.Identity.dll"]
```

Regards,

Comment: Does your certificate exist inside container? Also, why do you an API and mssql DB inside one container? Maybe it makes sense to use a `docker compose`?

Comment: i cant exec to the docker container to check if it is in there, since it is not running, yes u are right i will fix that but am just trying this first if its gonna work :(

Comment: Your `WriteLine` prints out the computed path, the very same path that it complains that the certificate is not found at, so that's not very useful. Can you actually print out if the file is there?

Comment: You may run `ls` before exporting a certificate and examine the output

Comment: yeb i fixed it thx mate